# Wrap all non-html numbers on site in a span

Tags: jquery, html, replace

So i have pieced together a couple of other peoples code to get it this far but it is having an issue when there are numbers in parts of the html of other elements. What i am trying to do is wrap all numbers on the page in a span. The code i have at the minute:

```
$(function(){
        $('#page').html(function(i, v) {
                            v = v.text();
            return v.replace(/(\d+)/g, '<span class="caps">$1</span>');
        });
    });
```

the problem with this though is if i have an image on my page with the file name of something like 'test123.png' it tries to wrap the 123 in a span.

How can i modify this code so that it only uses the text of elements and not the html?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This plugin is just what you need

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/

> jQuery replaceText will replace text in specified elements. Note that
>   only text content will be modified, leaving all tags and attributes
>   untouched.